# Excel VBA code for highlighting rows based on values in other cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel worksheet with a table in which column A represents the Bathc-ID. There are two additional cells named "identifier" and "key". Those two cells contain a drop-down menu from which the user can select the value for "identifier" and  "key".
The Batch ID has a two-digit code to the left of the hyphen and a 3- or 4-digit code to the right of the hyphen.  The first letter of the Batch ID is known as the Identifier and the leading number of the 3- or 4-digit code to the right of the hyphen is known as the Key.  For example, in the Batch ID "N9-363B", the Identifier is "N" and the Key is 3.
Based on the value chosen in the drop-down menu for the "identifier" and the "key" cells, the task is to highlight the entire row where the Batch-ID contains the selected values.

For example: If the user selects "H" in the "identifier" cell and "4" in the "key" cell, the program must highlight the rows where the identifier and the key of the Batch-ID match with the selected values.

I tried with this code but I get a Compile Error: Expected Array at line 9.
Can someone help me with this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightRows()
Dim nr As Integer, i As Integer, ID As String, key As Integer, A As String, B As Variant
nr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("A:A")) - 1
For i = 1 To nr
  A = Range("identifier")
  B = Range("key")
  ID = Range("A" & i)
  If Identifier(ID) = A And key(ID) = B Then
    Range("A" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Range("B" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    Range("C" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
  End If
Next i
End Sub

Function Identifier(ID As String) As String
Identifier = Left(ID, 1)
End Function

Function key(ID As String) As Integer
key = Left(Mid(ID, 4, 4), 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Get rid of `key As Integer` in your `Dim` statement.

Comment: This looks achievable with a Conditional Formatting formula..? No need for VBA.

Answer (score 0):

Line 9 is

```
If Identifier(ID) = A And key(ID) = B Then
```

Because you have declared `key` as just an Integer in

```
Dim nr As Integer, i As Integer, ID As String, **key As Integer,** A As String, B As Variant
```

The compiler is suggesting that `key(ID)` must mean an Integer Array. BUT... in actual fact `key()` is your function that is defined further down your code.

That is why BigBen's suggestion to remove the Dim works and doesn't produce any compile errors.
If you get something like this again, right click on the highlighted "variable" and choose "Definition" - it will take you to the `Dim` statement straight away, where you might have expected to go to the function.

But as CLR suggests - you could probably acheive this with standard Conditional Formatting rather than resorting to Code

Comment: I did it in this way and get a type mismatch error.

Comment: @SinisaArslanovic - If you do nothing else to your code other than remove the `key As Integer,` then the code compiles cleanly. If you are getting a type mismatch error then it is in code that you did not share with us

Answer (score 0):

Why would you consider doing such a thing using VBA if you can achieve it using "simple" conditional formatting :-)

The following screenshot contains a conditional formatting definition, based on the formula `=EXACT($B5,$C$2&$D$2)`:

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: I know it can be done simply with conditional formatting, but the task in the course I am attending requires me to write code.

Comment: @SinisaArslanovic: sorry, I didn't know your question was course related, I just assumed you needed a usable solution. That being said, you can always configure the conditional formatting, as I did, and record that as a VBA macro :-)